# WPF create filter by text box header column

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I'm trying to create a text based filter per column header in my dataGrid. I've managed to add the text boxes via data template.

So that once a user enters text into a column header text box, the grid will be filtered by that column only.

This is what it looks like

[image: column headers with individual filters]

but I can't figure out how do I use the TextChanged event since I'm getting a

> ResourceDictionary' root element requires a x:Class attribute to support event handlers in the XAML file

error.

this is my additions so far

```
<Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}" >
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Background="{DynamicResource ListHeaderBackgroundBrush}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                    <TextBox TextChanged="OnTextChanged"></TextBox> <!--per column filter-->
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>

                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
```

and here's the entire snippet, including a reference to how a column is defined.

```
 <Style x:Key="ExtraDataTabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}" >
        <Setter Property="Visibility"  Value="{Binding Path=HasItems, Converter={extensions:VisibilityConverter HideOnly=False}}" />
    </Style>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ExtraDataTabItemTemplate"  DataType="{x:Type my:StudyExtraDataViewModel}">
        <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <!-- Custom styling for context menu items -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ContextMenuItemStyle}">
    </Style>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:StudiesViewModel}">
        <Grid >
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}" >
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Background="{DynamicResource ListHeaderBackgroundBrush}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                    <TextBox TextChanged="OnTextChanged"></TextBox> <!--per column filter-->
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding StudiesGridHeight, Mode=TwoWay}" MinHeight="150"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding SeriesGridHeight, Mode=TwoWay}" MinHeight="200" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <controls:DataGridExtended  Grid.Row="0" x:Name="studiesGrid" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Studies}"
                                        EnableRowVirtualization ="False"
                                        Margin="10,10,10,10"
                                        AutoGenerateColumns ="False"
                                        AreRowDetailsFrozen="False"
                                        ColumnsPreferences="{Binding Path=Columns}"
                                        ColumnsForcedToPresent="{Binding Path=ColumnsForcedToPresent}"
                                        Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyleExtended}"
                                        UserSelectionChanged="OnUserSelectionChanged"
                                        SourceSelectionChanged="OnSourceSelectionChanged"                                                                                 
                                        ColumnHeaderContextMenu="{Binding Path=ColumnHeaderContextMenu}"
                                        >
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        <Setter Property="behaviors:ClickBehavior.DoubleClick" 
                                Value="{Binding ElementName=studiesGrid, Path=DataContext.StudyDoubleClickCommand}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
           
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    
                    <DataGridTextColumn controls:DataGridExtended.ColumnId="StudyId"
                                        Header="{wpfCommon:LocalizeExtension Key=StudyId, Type='Systems.CommonComponents.UI.StudySelectorWindow, CommonComponents'}"     
                                        Binding="{Binding StudyId}"
                                        ElementStyle="{DynamicResource TextBlockStyle}"
                                        CanUserSort="True">
                        

                    </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: I think the error message is clear. To attach an event handler the root element must set the x:Class attribute in order to allow having a partial class code-behind file that actually allows to define the event handler like your OnTextChanged handler.

Comment: @BionicCode

when setting StudiesViewModel as x:class i'm getting an error from the DataTemplrate DataType line

"    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:StudiesViewModel}">  "

also , the viewModel class inherits from a different class

Comment: No, the root element must be its own class. Then create a pratial class in a .cs file to have C# code. Same principle like MainWindow is the x:Class for the Window element and MainWindow.xaml.cs contains the partial class definition MainWindow. You can add your style to an element's ResourceDictionary  that already has a code-behind file liek MainWindow.Resources or Application.Resources (in App.xaml)

Comment: The *.cs file should be named like `MyResourceDictionary.xaml.cs` where `MyResourceDictionary.xaml` is the xaml filename.

Comment: the `x:Class` Attribute goes to the topmost element aka RootElement of the ResourceDictionary - not to a contained resource like a DataTemplate
The first line usually will look sth like `<ResourceDictionary x:Class="...."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Style` is defined in a `ResourceDictionary`, you need to add a code-behind class to it where you define the event handler.

1. Add the `x:Class` attribute to the root element of your XAML markup:

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                x:Class="YourProjectNamespace.MyResourceDictionary"
                ...
   ```
2. Add a class called MyResourceDictionary.**xaml.cs** (where "MyResourceDictionary" is the current name of your resource dictionary where the `Style` is defined) and derive it from `ResourceDictionary`.
3. Add the event handler to the new class:

   ```
    namespace YourProjectNamespace
    {
        partial class MyResourceDictionary : ResourceDictionary
        {
            public MyResourceDictionary()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                 //...
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: so how come  SourceSelectionChanged="OnSourceSelectionChanged" works?
you don't HAVE to have a code behind per file, right?